# Remove redundant square brackets in a list python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am working with a list of lists longitudes and latitudes. Each inner list has an extra pair or square brackets.

For instance:

```
[[-87.77621462941525,-87.77676645562643,-87.77906119123564]]
```

I would like to remove the extra brackets and be left with:

```
 [-87.77621462941525,-87.77676645562643,-87.77906119123564]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

this is nested list object, you can access the inner list with index.

```
In [1]: l = [[-87.77621462941525,-87.77676645562643,-87.77906119123564,]]

In [2]: l[0]
Out[2]: [-87.77621462941525, -87.77676645562643, -87.77906119123564]
```

Answer (score 4):

#### List Indexing

You can simply use list indexing.

```
my_lists = [[-87.77621462941525,-87.77676645562643,-87.77906119123564,]]
my_list  = my_lists[0]
```

#### [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=next#iterator.__next__)

Another way of doing this is using `next` which takes an iterable as an argument. It will raise a `StopIteration` in the case of the iterable being empty. You can prevent this by adding a default value as a second argument.

```
my_list = next(iter(my_lists))
```

Or

```
my_list = next(iter(my_list), [])  # Using [] here but the second argument can be anything, really
```

Obviously this second option might be a bit of overkill for your case but I find it a useful one-liner in many cases. For example:

```
next_element = next(iter(list_of_unknown_size), None)
```

Versus

```
next_element = list_of_unknown_size[0] if list_of_unknown_size else None
```